# Unable to see stacktrace with controller advice

Tags: spring-mvc, exception

I have implemented controlleradvice in my spring mvc project. Am able to see proper response but unable to find my stack trace. 
Here is my code, can any one tell me what should i do to get stack trace.....

```
@ExceptionHandler(Exception.class)
public ResponseEntity<?> handleException(final Exception exception) {

    err.setErrorMessage("server_error");

    return new ResponseEntity<ErrResp>(err,
            HttpStatus.OK);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
exception.getStackTrace();
```

You can assign this to a variable if needed or use the below to see stacktrace in console:

```
exception.printStackTrace();
```